# How to prevent duplication of module sources using npm?

Tags: node.js, module, npm, symlink

The scenario

- I have developed module-a & and module-b (depending on module-a)
- I have separate folders for module-a & module-b
- I create a project under app/ depending on module-b, so I run `npm install module-b`

The goal

- I want to **symlink module-b & module-a sources** in app/, this way change on are propaged without having to run `npm update`

How would you do this?

Comment: So install them side by side and then link module a into module b's node_modules folder.

Comment: It would duplicate module-a sources, it's what I want to avoid. I have edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This module does what I'm looking for : https://github.com/feross/zelda

Running `cd app & node zelda path/to/folder` will delete modules present in both app/ and path/to/folder and symlink them.

(Edit: I've made a preinstall script doing what I'm looking for : https://gist.github.com/dmail/c0a7901acba918c60ca3 because zelda is not exactly the same)